# dry-hopping what hops to use?

Tags: hops, dry-hopping

I am currently brewing a english pale ale and about to transfer from primary to secondary fermentor. I want to dry hop but dont know what people think would be the best hops to use. Any ideas or recomendations people have? The current hops in the recipe is 1oz. willemete and 1oz. fuggle...

Comment: This is really open-ended. You might try including your current recipe in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the style. As suggested, Fuggles (or Willamette) are natural in Brit beers. Goldings also.

But my FAVORITE dry hop for a British beer would be East Kent Goldings. You must try it.

It is a little pricier for East Kent Goldings but worth it. Goldings grown in the US or NZ will be good hops but will taste nothing at all like EK Goldings. (You could say that about all hops - true - but Goldings flavor profile seems to be especially affected by the soil profile).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the flavor you think would work best for your beer. Willamette is a hybrid of fuggle and will taste similar to it, a little more fruity or flowery. For english styles I generally fall back on Goldings which will give you a sweeter, more floral flavor, but it really depends on your preferences.